"Failed to load file referenced by SENTRY_PROPERTIES (sentry.properties)" when building xcode project
Getting this error when building a react-native project in xcode. More:
Run custom shell script 'Bundle React Navive code and images'
...
error: Failed to load file referenced by SENTRY_PROPERTIES (sentry.properties)
  caused by: Operation not permitted (os error 1)
thread 'main' panicked at 'Config not bound yet': src/config.rs:87

...but sentry.properties is present and readable in the /ios directory of my project

I needed to turn off the ENABLE_USER_SCRIPT_SANDBOXING in project Build Settings (folder icon in left-column toolbar; click your project name, choose "Build Settings" in the main panel, then scroll to it under "Build Options").
Apparently this sandboxing prevents access to the sentry.properties file in /ios.

If all your Sentry configs are as per the documentation provided officially, highly likely you have some mismatching dependencies.
Run the expo doctor command and confirm that you have no mismatching dependencies.
If you do, fix them.
